# How to manage the Refresh/Reload of a View on iOS?

Tags: ios5, refresh

I would like to make 3 things and I don't know how :(

- Make an automatic refresh every 5 minutes on my View Controllers
- Add a reload button on my NavigationBar
- Automatically close my app when passing in Background.

Is there any functions to initialiaze a refresh for example, a kind of countdown from the launch of the app ?

Thanks for all !

Answer (score 4):

The methods `[myView setNeedsDisplay];` and `[myTableView reloadData];` could help. You could start a timer at application launch and call those methods every 5 Minutes. But when you ask me... This doesn't make sense. Nobody is using an app longer than 1 or 2 Minutes most of the time.

Comment: Thanks for help. In my case, people can let the app run more than 5 minutes. That's why i need a refresh at least for 5 minutes.